# How to reduce code repetition if I want to run the same task operator multiple times in the same DAG?

Tags: airflow

How can I optimize this DAGs using best practices to minimize code repetition?

This dag runs several pipelines in Azure Data Factory and then it runs a Databricks notebook. The only difference between the ADF pipelines are the name of the pipeline, so I trying to find a way to reuse the Operator several times only changing the name of the pipeline.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.providers.microsoft.azure.operators.data_factory import (
    AzureDataFactoryRunPipelineOperator,
)

with DAG(
    dag_id=DAG_ID,
    start_date=datetime(2023, 3, 15),
    schedule="@daily",
    catchup=False,
    default_args=default_args,
    default_view="graph",
    tags=["development", "azure", "databricks"]
) as dag:

    run_adf_pipeline_1 = AzureDataFactoryRunPipelineOperator(
        task_id="run_adf_pipeline_1",
        pipeline_name="run_adf_pipeline_1",
    )

    run_adf_pipeline_2 = AzureDataFactoryRunPipelineOperator(
        task_id="run_adf_pipeline_2",
        pipeline_name="run_adf_pipeline_2",
    )

    run_adf_pipeline_3 = AzureDataFactoryRunPipelineOperator(
        task_id="run_adf_pipeline_3",
        pipeline_name="run_adf_pipeline_3",
    )

    run_adf_pipeline_4 = AzureDataFactoryRunPipelineOperator(
        task_id="run_adf_pipeline_4",
        pipeline_name="run_adf_pipeline_4",
    )

    new_cluster = {
        "spark_version": "10.4.x-scala2.12",
        "node_type_id": "Standard_DS3_v2",
        "num_workers": 1,
    }

    notebook_task_params = {
        "new_cluster": new_cluster,
        "notebook_task": {
            "notebook_path": DATABRICKS_NOTEBOOK_PATH,
        },
    }

    run_databricks_notebook = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
        task_id="run_databricks_notebook", json=notebook_task_params
    )

    [
        run_adf_pipeline_1,
        run_adf_pipeline_2,
        run_adf_pipeline_3,
        run_adf_pipeline_4
    ] >> run_databricks_notebook
```

I tried using a `PythonOperator` that uses a for loop calling the `AzureDataFactoryRunPipelineOperator`, but in this way the operator will run sequentially and I don't specifically need that.

```
AZURE_DATA_FACTORY_PIPELINES = [
        run_adf_pipeline_1,
        run_adf_pipeline_2,
        run_adf_pipeline_3,
        run_adf_pipeline_4,
    ]

def run_adf_pipelines(pipelines: List[str]) -> None:
    for pipeline in pipelines:
        AzureDataFactoryRunPipelineOperator(
            task_id=pipeline,
            pipeline_name=pipeline,
        )

with DAG(
    dag_id=DAG_ID,
    start_date=datetime(2023, 3, 15),
    schedule="@daily",
    catchup=False,
    default_args=default_args,
    default_view="graph",
    tags=["development", "azure", "databricks"],
) as dag:

    run_adf_ingestion_pipelines = PythonOperator(
        task_id="run_adf_ingestion_pipelines",
        python_callable=run_adf_pipelines,
        op_kwargs={"pipelines": AZURE_DATA_FACTORY_PIPELINES},
    )

    new_cluster = {
        "spark_version": "10.4.x-scala2.12",
        "node_type_id": "Standard_DS3_v2",
        "num_workers": 1,
    }

    notebook_task_params = {
        "new_cluster": new_cluster,
        "notebook_task": {
            "notebook_path": DATABRICKS_NOTEBOOK_PATH,
        },
    }

    run_databricks_notebook = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
        task_id="run_databricks_notebook", json=notebook_task_params
    )

    run_adf_ingestion_pipelines >> run_databricks_notebook
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always iterate over the pipeline names and collect a list of Azure Data Factory tasks to run in parallel before running the Databricks tasks.

Something like:

```py
from datetime import datetime

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.providers.databricks.operators.databricks import DatabricksSubmitRunOperator
from airflow.providers.microsoft.azure.operators.data_factory import AzureDataFactoryRunPipelineOperator


with DAG(
    dag_id="multiple_adf_pipelines",
    start_date=datetime(2023, 3, 15),
    schedule="@daily",
    catchup=False,
    default_view="graph",
    tags=["development", "azure", "databricks"],
) as dag:
    AZURE_DATA_FACTORY_PIPELINES = [
        "run_adf_pipeline_1",
        "run_adf_pipeline_2",
        "run_adf_pipeline_3",
        "run_adf_pipeline_4",
    ]
    adf_tasks = []
    for pipeline in AZURE_DATA_FACTORY_PIPELINES:
        t = AzureDataFactoryRunPipelineOperator(
            task_id=pipeline,
            pipeline_name=pipeline,
        )
        adf_tasks.append(t)

    new_cluster = {
        "spark_version": "10.4.x-scala2.12",
        "node_type_id": "Standard_DS3_v2",
        "num_workers": 1,
    }

    notebook_task_params = {
        "new_cluster": new_cluster,
        "notebook_task": {
            "notebook_path": "DATABRICKS_NOTEBOOK_PATH",
        },
    }

    run_databricks_notebook = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
        task_id="run_databricks_notebook", json=notebook_task_params
    )

    adf_tasks >> run_databricks_notebook
```

[image]